# How to write the Redis DB values into excel sheet?

Tags: java, excel, redis, apache-poi, jedis

I am using the Redis db manager and the client is Jedis .

I have executed the two  below queries using java

```
System.out.println("Alphabets:"+Jedis.smembers("SET Name");

System.out.println("Books:"+Jedis.hgetall("key","value");
```

The outputs are  below,

> 1.First Print Statement output
>
> Alphabets:[A,B,C,D,]
>
> 2.Second Print Statement output
>
> Books : Cookbook=[Vishnu,JavaBook=Balaguru,Macbook=Steve]

Here I want to write the above output values into single excel sheet with the below format

**Title : Alphabets List**

> No   Alphabets
>
> 1. A
> 2. B
> 3. C
> 4. D
>
> **Title : Books List**
>
> No.   Book Name.     BookAuthor
>
> 1. Cookbook.         Vishnu
> 2. JavaBook.          Balaguru
> 3. MacBook            Steve

Alphabets are values in the [Redis SET Command to get the SET values](https://redis.io/commands/smembers)

Book Name is the key and BookAuthor  is the value in [Redis Hash](https://redis.io/commands/hgetall) for Second Print Statement output

I have seen many tutorials get the values from array and writing into excel sheet dynamically with Apache poi.but the results I am getting is not looking like an array here.

Every time am getting more values in the results ,is there any way dynamically write into excel.

my problem is exactly how to pass printed output values into excel objects and write into excel dynamically

Kindly help me on this.

Thanks for your help in  advance.

Comment: [Jedis.smembers](http://static.javadoc.io/redis.clients/jedis/2.9.0/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.html#smembers-java.lang.String-) returns a `Set` and [Jedis.hgetAll](http://static.javadoc.io/redis.clients/jedis/2.9.0/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.html#hgetAll-java.lang.String-) returns a `Map`. But both takes only **one** parameter and not two. Read about using `Set` and `Map` in [tutorial about Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/TOC.html) since they are `Collections`.

Comment: Yeah you are right ,but if I have more key and values in single hash then hget all bring them all @Axel Richter

Comment: I have passed only one parameter with correct syntax and getting the output ,my query here is how to write into excel sheet

Comment: The link you shared is useful for me I will go through now @Axel Richter

Comment: Book Name is fields and Book Author is my values in the Redis hash @Axel Richter

Comment: Do you intend on writing your worksheet using only Apache POI or have you considered another alternatives?

Comment: Apache poi is the best alternative I heard .but if there is any other alternatives with ease of use is also good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with either Apache POI or Jasper Reports.

## Apache POI

```
package q46617008;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ApacheExample
{

    public void build( WorksheetExample w ) throws Exception
    {

        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook( );

        Sheet s = wb.createSheet( );
        // If you need to name it:
        // String name = WorkbookUtil.createSafeSheetName( "the name!" );
        // Sheet s = wb.createSheet( name );

        Row titleRow = s.createRow( 0 );
        Cell titleCell = titleRow.createCell( 0 );
        titleCell.setCellValue( "Alphabets List" );

        Row r;
        Cell c;
        int i = 1;
        Iterator< String > alphabetsIterator = WorksheetExample.alphabets.iterator( );
        while ( alphabetsIterator.hasNext( ) )
        {
            String alphabet = alphabetsIterator.next( );
            r = s.createRow( i );
            c = r.createCell( 0 );
            c.setCellValue( alphabet );
            i++;
        }

        // Skip one line to start books list title.
        // If you need this in another sheet, just create it:
        // s = wb.createSheet();
        i++;
        titleRow = s.createRow( i );
        titleCell = titleRow.createCell( 0 );
        titleCell.setCellValue( "Books List" );

        // Skip one line to start books list.
        i++;
        Iterator< Entry< String, String > > booksIterator = WorksheetExample.books.entrySet( ).iterator( );
        while ( booksIterator.hasNext( ) )
        {
            Entry< String, String > book = booksIterator.next( );
            r = s.createRow( i );
            c = r.createCell( 0 );
            c.setCellValue( book.getKey( ) + ". " + book.getValue( ) );
            i++;
        }

        OutputStream fileOut = Files.newOutputStream( w.file, StandardOpenOption.CREATE );
        wb.write( fileOut );
        fileOut.close( );

        wb.close( );
    }

}
```

The result will be something like:
[image: Result]

---

## Jasper Reports

You will need a Jasper Report `JRXML` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.1  -->
<!-- 2017-10-13T16:31:09 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Worksheet" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0c9a4a90-2d7f-4793-bf61-9f72221b82b4">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="AlphabetsDataSet" uuid="725922ca-545f-4070-b9ed-5d9cd64508ff">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="_THIS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="BooksDataSet" uuid="f06a8881-d9b9-42dc-90c3-ee1f748045e6">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="_THIS" class="java.util.Map.Entry"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="Alphabets" class="java.util.Set" nestedType="String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="Books" class="java.util.Map"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <detail>
        <band height="120" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20" uuid="6b9870c0-49f9-4540-ba5e-f131def81859"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Alphabets List]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="70" width="555" height="20" uuid="5d2a371c-4141-4728-afcf-6bdd326d4a40"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Books List]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="20" width="555" height="30" uuid="5bca4983-9df0-4eee-8a5b-9cf3d5ef6965">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="AlphabetsDataSet" uuid="e998d7ad-a964-447e-b3e7-b7ebfd6ed06b">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{Alphabets})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="120" uuid="739ad6b0-e886-4d7f-92d6-2cf0ef204ed6">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="30" uuid="c02e9247-104c-426b-b538-27c048d213ac"/>
                                <box padding="5"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{_THIS}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="90" width="555" height="30" uuid="1ecc6ba3-a20e-4978-aee9-4113907135c7">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="BooksDataSet" uuid="c09b4524-202e-436e-b6ba-74571e14c9af">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{Books}.entrySet())]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="120" uuid="397f69ae-2f85-44fd-85fc-bca177628dab">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="30" uuid="8d5fd0a8-7921-4871-8aa8-5360ac440f49"/>
                                <box padding="5"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{_THIS}.getKey()+". "+$F{_THIS}.getValue()]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

For this example, save it as `Worksheet.jrxml` somewhere, but remember the path as we will use it in the next step.

For the Java implementation:

```
package q46617008;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRXlsxExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleExporterInput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput;

public class JasperExample
{

    private Map< String, Object > parameters;

    private String filePath = "C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\Worksheet.jrxml";

    public JasperExample( ) {

        parameters = new HashMap<>( );
        // Define your locale or set it as a parameter
        parameters.put( JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, new Locale( "pt", "BR" ) );
        parameters.put( "Alphabets", WorksheetExample.alphabets );
        parameters.put( "Books", WorksheetExample.books );
    }

    public void exportPDF( WorksheetExample w ) throws Exception
    {

        JRDataSource reportDataSource = new JREmptyDataSource( 1 );

        JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport( filePath );

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport( report, parameters, reportDataSource );

        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter( );
        exporter.setExporterInput( new SimpleExporterInput( jasperPrint ) );
        exporter.setExporterOutput( new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput( Files.newOutputStream( w.file, StandardOpenOption.CREATE ) ) );

        exporter.exportReport( );
    }

    public void exportXLSX( WorksheetExample w ) throws Exception
    {

        JRDataSource reportDataSource = new JREmptyDataSource( 1 );

        JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport( filePath );

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport( report, parameters, reportDataSource );

        JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter( );
        exporter.setExporterInput( new SimpleExporterInput( jasperPrint ) );
        exporter.setExporterOutput( new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput( Files.newOutputStream( w.file, StandardOpenOption.CREATE ) ) );

        exporter.exportReport( );
    }

}
```

The result will be something like:
[image: Jasper: left is XLSX, right is PDF]
On the left you see the XLSX output. On the right is the PDF version.

Of course, there's plenty of space for optimization.
For example, you could save the compiled JRXML and load it, which is way faster than compiling it everytime you need it.

---

## Running it

If you need a simple class to run those two examples, use this one:

```
package q46617008;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class WorksheetExample
{

    public static final Set< String > alphabets = new HashSet<>( );

    public static final Map< String, String > books = new HashMap<>( );

    public final Path file;

    public WorksheetExample( String fileName ) {
        file = Paths.get( "C:", "Path", "To", "Your", fileName );
    }

    static
    {
        alphabets.add( "A" );
        alphabets.add( "B" );
        alphabets.add( "C" );
        alphabets.add( "D" );

        books.put( "Cookbook", "Vishnu" );
        books.put( "JavaBook", "Balaguru" );
        books.put( "MacBook", "Steve" );
    }

    public static void main( String[ ] args ) throws Exception
    {

        WorksheetExample w;

        w = new WorksheetExample( "ApacheExample.xlsx" );
        new ApacheExample( ).build( w );

        w = new WorksheetExample( "JasperExample.xlsx" );
        new JasperExample( ).exportXLSX( w );

        w = new WorksheetExample( "JasperExample.pdf" );
        new JasperExample( ).exportPDF( w );
    }

}
```

Comment: how to award the Bounty to the specific user

Comment: @vidya it's automatic when the bounty ends. You don't need to do anything. I am glad my answer worked for you!